# R run sweave (Rnw) file from an R script

Tags: r, sweave

I would like to run sweave from an R script. The Rnw file is in an Rnw directory just below my project directory. I tried this

```
system("Rnw/compilePDF.Rnw")
```

And got this response.

```
sh: Rnw/compilePDF.Rnw: Permission denied
```

The permissions on the .Rnw file are -rw-r--r-- but I suspect that is not the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to include the following bits of code. The encoding is needed because Sweave default is ASCII and returns an error to this effect.

```
Sweave("Rnw/compilePDF.Rnw", encoding = "UTF-8")
```

The output of the command is

```
Writing to file compilePDF.tex
Processing code chunks with options ...

You can now run (pdf)latex on ‘compilePDF.tex’
```

To convert this to pdf use

```
tools::texi2pdf("Rnw/compilePDF.tex")
```